# Texture does not show with loop

Tags: opengl

Follow up questions:

- Do I need to set different active textures for FBOs? This might be the cause, because I am not taking that into account. Either way, there is something wrong with my active textures. If I set active texture to TEXTURE_1 before this all, I do get a texture for the object (however the wrong one).

  ```
  for (int side = 0; side < 2; side++)
  {

      glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Delete this line and a, wrong, texure pops up for the second iteration
      glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, modelsFboId[side]);

      glViewport(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight);
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      gluPerspective(SCREEN_FOV, SCREEN_RAT, NEAR, FAR);
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
      glLoadIdentity();
      glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
      glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,
          GL_NICEST);
      glDisable(GL_BLEND);
      glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
      glDepthMask(true);
      glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
      glClearDepth(1.0f);
      glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

      glLoadIdentity (); 

      camera.look();

      drawObject();

      glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

      glPopAttrib();
  }
  ```

I loop over two fbo's which are both created in a loop as well. The fbo's work fine, however the second iteration the texture doesn't want to bind. I tried switching to different active texture for the second iteration, I have a shader which I disabled, I tried setting the clientactivetexture as well. If I skip the first iteration nothing the second loop works. When I attach a color instead of a texture the object DOES show (it doesn't show at all with the texture bound).

I tried tracking down this bug for a good two days now to no avail.

Also, after this loop, I have a second loop which is the same, except it uses a display list, and it works fine for both iterations, which might indicate something.

```
    for (int side = 0; side < 2; side++) {
        modelsFboId[side] = glGenFramebuffersEXT();                                     
        modelsFboTextureId[side] = glGenTextures();                                     
        modelsDepthRenderBufferId[side] = glGenRenderbuffersEXT();

        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, modelsFboId[side]);    

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, modelsFboTextureId[side]);                             
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);                       
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);           
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_INT, (java.nio.ByteBuffer) null); 
        glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, modelsFboTextureId[side], 0); 

        glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, modelsDepthRenderBufferId[side]);         
        glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT,GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, modelsDepthRenderBufferId[side]); 
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
      }
```

drawObject():

```
   // using bind slick, texture int doesn't change in this function nor any other

    if (textureMode == 1) {
        glColor3f(color.x, color.y, color.z);
    } else if (textureMode == 0) {
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        textures[texture].bind();
    }

    glPushMatrix();
    ..rotations.. all seems definitely fine here and certainly doesn't change in correspondence to the prev iteration.

    .. draw actual object.. tried LWJGL sphere, a simple cube and some other LWJGL objects
    glPopMatrix();

    if (textureMode == 0)
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

array inits..

```
int skyFboId[] = {-1, -1};
int skyFboTextureId[] = {-1, -1};

int modelsFboId[] = {-1, -1};
int modelsFboTextureId[] = {-1, -1};
int modelsDepthRenderBufferId[] = {-1, -1};

int listModelsFboId[] = {-1, -1};
int listModelsFboTextureId[] = {-1, -1};
int listModelsDepthRenderBufferId[] = {-1, -1};
int listModelsTextureLocation = -1;
```

Comment: What's the question? If the second loop works, why not use it? (Although, it doesn't look like any texture data is ever uploaded - so not sure how that works.) Also, your first loop is a mess. It's doing a lot of unnecessary work - you're setting the viewport multiple times; you're enabling texture2D, not using it, then disabling it; setting the modelview matrix to identity twice. And most importantly, you're not ever setting up the FBO you want to draw into. Maybe step back and make sure you understand what each call is intended to do, then debug by stepping and making sure each line works.

Comment: Yes, it's a mess! Sorry! I'm new to Opengl and learning as I go. I know what each call does however, I'm not to sure always when it's necessary to call them.. I will dive into that right away. However, I would think that overhead would not be an issue(?). I know the texture is properly uploaded since it shows in the first iteration, not in the second. I need the first loop not to be a displaylist since it is updated every frame and using a list would slow it down.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup! 2 questions: 1) Where is your texture uploaded? 2) What is the code for `drawObject()`?

Comment: My textures are uploaded at start. I'll add the code for drawObject as well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm strongly beginning to think this is a driver issue (they've been reported for my gpu)

Comment: Could be. I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you've posted, though you've left a lot out. (Are you modifying the texture matrix, for example?) Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to ensure that all values are set as you think they should be?

Comment: I've ran the code on another pc and it popped up an error. So I have something to investigate now. Either way, thanks for your time, really appreciated.

Comment: The error was a driver specific issue which I fixed and was unrelated. I now have a reproduced case of the bug described here. I'll try to add more code which is of consequence to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Slick library needs to unbind the texture with TextureImpl.unbind().